# Recommended approach to access multiple variables of other function

Tags: javascript

What is the recommended approach to access other function variables in another function. My functionA currently holds 25 variables and contains a complex logic developed. The variables currently in FunctionA are only to be accessed in the functionB so cannot declare in higher scope or global variables. Any suggestions to make the variables accessible in function B only

Comment: Could you provide a code example? Does return not work?

Comment: Is function A called by function B? Function B called by function A? Functions A then B called from function C?

Comment: Why dont you send them to function B as parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use return statement to return multiple values like this

```
 return {
        A: x,
        B: y,
        C: ts,
        D: z
    }
```

To access you can use

```
 p=function B();
 console.log(p.A) // x
 console.log(p.B) // y
```

Answer (score 0):

If Sids solution is not what you want, since the question is not clear on the execution order, you could always create your own scope/namespace:

```
;var MyLogic = {
    _V1: null, //Some variables
    _V2: null, //Some variables

    //Both functions access the variables in MyLogic
    FuncA: function(){
        console.log(this._V1, this._V2)
    },

    //Both functions access the variables in MyLogic
    FuncB: function(){
        this._V1 = 'hello';
        this._V2 = 45.55
    }
};

MyLogic.FuncB();
MyLogic.FuncA();
```